# Why language change in lightdm-gtk-greeter is taken into account on second login?

Tags: lightdm, lightdm-gtk-greeter

I am using lightdm with Xfce and when I change language in the greater and login Xfce uses old setting. However, after logout and another login language is properly changed and Xfce uses intended language. It looks like there is one login lag. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I think lightdm like all dm (xdm, gdm, ...) is start one time by the Xserver.
At this time, lightdm read his config files.
When you log in, lightdm go to background. you don't see it but it' always running.
When you log out, lightdm come back on the screen but it don't re-read his config files.
If you want to change that, you must restart lightdm.
I look in the man pages of lightdm and dm-tool but find nothing, except perhaps dm-tool switch-to-greeter but I don't try.
Did you change a lot of time the lightdm config ?

Comment: No, I do not change config very often. However, I am preparing virtual machine drive image which I would like to be user friendly. Now I have to put steps like choose keyboard layout from the list of all possible layouts (couldn't that be limited?) and then login, logout and login once again to properly set language.